# How to download images and store in sdcard in android?

Tags: android, android-image

I am prepared code for download images from server and store in sdcard.For that i have prepared code,

```
 URL url;
 try {
     url = new URL("http://myserver_path/applikaza/appstore/apks/ScrResoluton/scrresolution.jpg");
     input = url.openStream();
     String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
     String basepath = storagePath + "/Guayama/" + folderName;
     output = new FileOutputStream(basepath + "/home.png");
     byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];

     int bytesRead = 0;
     while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
         output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }

 } catch (MalformedURLException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     output.close();
     input.close();
 }
```

but got NullPointerException at  `output.close()`.I think done mistake some where .please help me.

Comment: you are using path E:/Suresh/images/home.png, this is your computer path. So how android device understand this url?

Comment: `E:/Suresh/images/home.png` is that your server path?

Comment: just now i change path.....after changed path i got "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: You need to use AsyncTask to do the download, you should not use the Network on the main UI thread.

Comment: ya... now only i created AsyncTask.It is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get a NullPointerException at output.close() is because your URL is incorrectly formed. For starters, it doesn't contain a valid protocol. This will cause MalformedURLException to be thrown on the line

```
url = new URL("E:/Suresh/images/home.png");
```

and you'll then go straight to the catch block, followed by the finally block which calls output.close(), but output is null since the line

```
output = new FileOutputStream(basepath + "/home.png");
```

was never executed.

You need to correct your URL (see the description [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String%29)) and you need to correct your exception handling, as in the case of MalformedURLException, this will only ever be thrown where you set the value of url, and so you will never have a non-null value for output or input when your "finally" block is executed.

Your URL should probably be of the form "http://something/Suresh/images/home.png" or maybe "file://something/Suresh/images/home.png".  If the home.png file is located on another machine to the Android device, try and access it via a web browser and use the URL shown by the web browser complete with "http://".

Comment: just now i change path.....after changed path i got "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: This means you're trying to access the network from the user interface thread, which is nearly always a bad idea. You should look into android threading and create a separate thread to do this network access and communicate back to the UI thread (there are loads of examples around if you search). If you want to temporarily work round this, you could make your app target an earlier android version (before Honeycomb) as accessing the network from the UI thread didn't raise the exception pre-honeycomb (however, this is not a good long term solution if you're doing anything other than playing).